# Dictionary losing its values somehow?

Tags: c#, dictionary

I have a dictionary,

```
private Dictionary<int, int> dict = new Dictionary<int, int>();
```

I call a foreach loop to go through my dataTable and populate the dictionary,

```
foreach (DataRow row in SubVwr.Tables[0].Tbl.Rows)
{
    dict.Add(Convert.ToInt32(row["ItemNo"]), (int)row["QtyRcvd"]);
}
```

Later, in a different method that's called I want to recall some values from my dictionary using the following code

```
int QtyChanged = (int)row["QtyRcvd"] - dict[Convert.ToInt32(row["ItemNo"])];
```

This throws an exception because the dictionary 'doesn't have that value' which it should. I've tried printing out all of the values in the dictionary just after their added and it's all there. but when I try and print it just before calling it in the other method above, it doesn't print anything. because supposedly it's blank. Does anyone see something I'm not seeing as to how this is happening?

---

These methods are driven by a wpf button, in an mvvm System this is all taking place in the corresponding viewmodel

```
private void ReceiveOrder(object sender)
{
    //log each QtyRcvd for later comparison
    foreach (DataRow row in SubVwr.Tables[0].Tbl.Rows)
    {
        dict.Add(Convert.ToInt32(row["ItemNo"]), (int)row["QtyRcvd"]);
        Console.Out.WriteLine(dict[Convert.ToInt32(row["ItemNo"])]);
    }

    foreach (KeyValuePair<int, int> kvp in dict)
    {
        //textBox3.Text += ("Key = {0}, Value = {1}", kvp.Key, kvp.Value);
        Console.Out.WriteLine("Key = {0}, Value = {1}", kvp.Key, kvp.Value);
    }

    ReceiveOrderDialogWindow dialog = new ReceiveOrderDialogWindow()
    {
        Topmost = true
    };

    dialog.ShowDialog();
}
```

Second call, once button is clicked inside of the ReceiveOrderDialogWindow

```
  private void requestSerials(object sender)
    {
        CommandsViewModel commands = new CommandsViewModel(new ModulesViewModel());

        //for each row in our received order..
        foreach (DataRow row in SubVwr.Tables[0].Tbl.Rows)
        {
            foreach (KeyValuePair<int, int> kvp in dict)
            {
                //textBox3.Text += ("Key = {0}, Value = {1}", kvp.Key, kvp.Value);
                Console.Out.WriteLine("Key = {0}, Value = {1}", kvp.Key, kvp.Value);
            }
            int QtyChanged = (int)row["QtyRcvd"] - dict[Convert.ToInt32(row["ItemNo"])];
```

[image: Console output]

Comment: The only way a Dictionary could loose values is if you remove them. Maybe you accdidently create a new instance that is freshly initialized, just with some values no longer being there in teh datasource?

Comment: We need to see more code.  Something is happening between where you populated it and where you're using it, but you didn't include that "something".  We need a [mcve]

Comment: Make sure your dictionary populating code is called. BTW, `ubVwr.Tables[0].Tbl.Rows`... What is .Tbl.?

Comment: Maybe `row["ItemNo"]` points to a different value or a different "row" that it was added? It's difficult to tell when there isn't complete code of what's going on.

Comment: There's definitely no other instance being created. SubVwr.Tables[0].Tbl is a dataTable, like I said that's where the data is being pulled from and that works.

Comment: @Tristan, please, share more code. What is shown here is bit ugly, but should work, so issue is somewhere else.

Comment: Better.  Please also add your console output, and also confirm that there are no other references to your `dict` not included in the question.

Comment: I've looked over it multiple times, and there are no references to dict outside of the ones posted.

Comment: `dict` appears to be a field belonging to the class(es) in which the two methods you've shown are defined. But we know that they're not the same *instance* of the class, even if it's one class, because we see you construct a new instance at the end of `ReceiveOrder`. And there's no attempt (shown) to pass the `dict` that you've populated into the `dialog` instance.

Comment: Isn't the whole point of an MVVM system to keep the data outside of the view?? I should be able to contain it within the viewmodel. I don't want to pass the data to a wpf window.

Comment: Youd need to demo some sample data going in.

Comment: Reminder (due to title): it's == it is; its == belongs to it

Comment: I found a solution, but the question has been put on hold...? Because it's desired result wasn't clear enough......? clearly I want the dictionary to NOT lose it's values. did that really need to be stated explicitly? do you people just love to flex your points on newer users?

Comment: Is there sufficient information, currently, contained in the question to determine the result or did you have to rely upon information that only you had access to? The question was put on hold because five people believed that there was insufficient information supplied - and it certainly wasn't enough information to be able to run it for ourselves.

Comment: There was enough information, as much information as there was to give. Making the dictionary static fixed my problem. I also posted any and all information requested. why even bother to ask , or to have me do that if you were planning on calling it insufficient anyways.

Comment: No, there was not enough information.  That's why several of us asked for more code and a [mcve], which still has not been supplied.  You improved your question, yes, but the improvement isn't enough for us to identify the issue without guessing blindly.

Comment: Take it on the chin, learn from your mistakes, move on and next time ask a more comprehensive question. Getting upset about a closed question is silly, you fixed the problem anyway so happy days.

Comment: @Tristan `Making the dictionary static fixed my problem.` This proves Damien's point, that you were using different instances of the same class. In all likelihood, even though `static` has solved your problem for now, issues like these are often rooted in a less-than-perfect OOP approach, which is likely going to spawn more issues. A more fitting solution would be to e.g. overload the `ReceiveOrderDialogWindow` constructor to take a dictionary as parameter, so that you can pass the dictionary from one instance of `ReceiveOrderDialogWindow` to another. The shortest solution is not the best one.